# Passing Session Id using URL instead of HTTP headers

Tags: api, authentication, tooling-api, session, identity

**When invoking the Tooling API, is there a way to pass the Session Id using just URL parameters?**

I've seen a couple of Salesforce APIs that work when the Session Id is contained in a URL parameter:

1. This works with the [Identity URL](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_using_openid.htm&language=en_US):

   `GET https://na1.salesforce.com/id/[org_id]/[user_id]?oauth_token=[session_id]`
2. This works with [Frontdoor.jsp for logging into Salesforce](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter14/release-notes/security_frontdoorjsp.htm):

   `GET https://na1.salesforce.com/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=[session_id]`

Now I'm looking at the [Tooling API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/api_tooling.pdf) which contains several GET-accessible operations, including Execute Anonymous (I appreciate the risk of this) and wondering if there is a way to do:

`GET https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v28.0/tooling/executeAnonymous/?...`

There are some docs on [using the access token](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_using_access_token.htm&language=en_US) that seem to indicate the Identity URL might be a special case where that was permitted, else it must go in an header (for REST) or body (for SOAP).

Any ideas that don't use headers? RFC 3986 `https://username:password@` was a non starter ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, While using rest api it is mandatory to pass the session id / token in headers as passing it in query string will be very high security risk.